# argument name in the lua function call

Tags: function, lua, arguments

I am looking for a more pleasant way to add an argument name while calling a function.

Something which is better than either of these

```
local ret =  foo( --[[argNam1 =]] true)
local ret =  foo( true ) -- first argument is argName1
```

I tried

```
local ret =  foo( argNam1 = true)
```

but I got error

```
')' expected near '='
```

Comment: You can use `local ret =  foo{ argNam1 = true }` if `foo `is defined as follows: `function foo(t) local argNam1 = t.argNam1; ... end`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, This is a cool trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use named parameters, if that's what you want. Lua tables are good for imitating that behavior. So instead of passing all parameters separated by a comma, you pass a single table object; that has named keys.

If that is your `foo()` function:

```
local foo(parameters)
    print(parameters.argNam1)
end
```

Then you could call it like: `local ret = foo{argNam1 = true}`
Or call it like this:

```
local arguments = {
    argNam1 = true,
    argNam2 = "foobar"
}
local ret = foo(arguments)
```